# How do I get these points on Open Street Map with QGIS 3.03

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I'm totally newbie with any GIS. I have an excel file with few coordinate points that I would like to have on Open Street Map at QGIS 3.03.

I can see the points and I can see the map, but points are not on the map. I guess there is something wrong with the coordinates, but I can't figure out what. Points should be in Helsinki, Finland.

The points are (XY):

```
25504048.339295186,6678318.63569837
25498570.47469425,6681280.528837938
25498588.903816383,6676346.348857614
25501320.605564777,6683454.164717192
25499216.654747352,6684094.233741575
25505079.153743148,6672807.205711159
```

What should I do to show them in correct location? 
(Simple and every step instructions, please)

I would also like to know, how to get shortest route between the points.

Comment: Do you know the projection those coordinates are in? That will make the process much quicker to convert into WGS84.

Comment: Your coordinates are not in Pseudo Mercator (EPSG:3857), what OSM uses. I've searched epsg.io for projections of Finland, but none of them fits to your coordinates. X coordinates are extremely large.

Comment: I have no idea about the projection.

Answer (score 3):

The points seem to be in EPSG:3879 ETRS89 / GK25FIN which places them around Helsinki:

[image]

You can save them from Excel to CSV and load that into QGIS with `Add delimited text`, or use the `XYtools` plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still wasn't easy task, but I managed to do it.

Comment: That's quite normal for GIS. You have to learn a lot at first, doing many mistakes.